# Clean up JavaScript timestamp

Tags: javascript

I'm using this javascript code to sync the client time with my server time

```
var offset = 0;

function calcOffset() {
  var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://stackoverflow.com/", false);
  xmlhttp.send();

  var dateStr = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Date');
  var serverTimeMillisGMT = Date.parse(new Date(Date.parse(dateStr)).toUTCString());
  var localMillisUTC = Date.parse(new Date().toUTCString());

  offset = serverTimeMillisGMT -  localMillisUTC;
}

function getServerTime() {
  var date = new Date();

  date.setTime(date.getTime() + offset);

  return date;
}
```

the date I get back is

```
 "2013-10-03T16:37:05.568Z"
```

How to I make this "2013-10-03 H:i:s"?

Comment: If you are working with dates, http://momentjs.com/ is a great resource. Javscript's native handling for dates isn't very clean or smooth. That being said, there is an answer to this in vanilla JS which I'll put up if I can get it there before anyone else, hah.

Comment: What does H:i:s mean Hour:i:Seconds? What's up with the I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a smoother way to do it if you are working with a bunch of dates, here's a way to do it with vanilla JS:

```
x = new Date
x.getFullYear() + '-' + x.getMonth() + '-' + x.getDay()
```

**Edit:**

Here it is with the time and leading zeros on the month and day, as you can see these extra things add a good bit more code. Maybe if you post another question detailing your troubles with moment.js, we would be able to help getting it fixed:

```
formatDate(new Date);

function formatDate(d){
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var month = addLeadingZero(d.getMonth());
  var day = addLeadingZero(d.getDay());
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();
  var seconds = d.getSeconds();
  return year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds
}

function addLeadingZero(n){ return n < 10 ? '0'+n : ''+n }
```

Comment: moment.js is super awesome.

Comment: Except I'm using it with firebase to get the current time without page refresh and it's (moment.js) not working.